# I can't return the substring() data with any function types in my own string function

Tags: c++, string, function, return-value

I'm trying to create my own string,
I have problem in creating substr() function,
I can't return the value, all I can do is print the value by void function.

```
char String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const
{
    for (size_t i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        return m_Data[i];
    }
} // it won't work correctly
```

---

(m_Data is char*).

---

```
void String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const
{
    for (size_t i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << m_Data[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
} // it works correctly
```

---

This is my whole class :

```
class String
{
public:
    // " l " stands for local

    String(); //default

    String(const char* l_Value);

    String(const String& l_other) ; // copy assignment

    String(String&& l_other) noexcept;//move constructor

    String& operator =(String&& l_other) noexcept; //move assingment

    ~String(); //Destructor

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& l_stream, const String& l_other);

public:

     void SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const;


private:
    //" m " stands for private member
    char* m_Data;
    size_t m_Size;

};
```

---

I've tried casting.
or other type of function .

like:

```
char String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const
{
    for (size_t i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        return m_Data[i];
    }
} // it won't work correctly
```

---

or:

```
String String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const
{
    for (size_t i = start; i < end + 1; i++)
    {
        return m_Data[i];
    }
} // it won't work correctly
```

none of them solved my problem.

Comment: Remember that `return` returns *immediately*. You try to return a single character multiple times inside a loop. You need to create a new `String` object inside the function, set its size (not forgetting the null-terminator) and then copy the characters into the new object one by one. Then *after* the loop you return the new `String` object.

Comment: Unrelated. The comment _`// copy assignment`_ should be `// copy constructor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you return the first `char` in the range. The function is equivalent to:

```cpp
char String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const
{
    return m_Data[start];
}
```

You could add a constructor to create a new string from a range:

```cpp
String(const char* l_first, const char* l_last) :
    m_Data(new char[std::distance(l_first, l_last) + 1]),
    m_Size(std::distance(l_first, l_last))
{
    std::copy(l_first, l_last, m_Data);
    m_Data[m_Size] = '\0';
}
```

Then use that in `SubString`:

```cpp
String String::SubString(const size_t& start, const size_t& end) const {
    return String(m_Data + start, m_Data + end);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `SubString` function to return a string **you have to create a new string**. You need a constructor that can create a string of a given size. Then you can copy the characters from the old string to the new string.

Something like this

```
class String
{
public:
    String(); //default
    String(size_t size); // create a string with the given size
    ...
    String SubString(size_t start, size_t end) const;
    ...
};


String String::SubString(size_t start, size_t end) const
{
    // create a new string with the correct size
    String new_string(end - start);
    // copy the characters from the old string to the new string
    for (size_t i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        new_string->m_Data[i - start] = m_Data[i];
    }
    // return the new string
    return new_string;
}
```

Now to make this work I added a new constructor `String(size_t size)`. I haven't written the code for that because I can't see the code for your other constructors, so I'm not sure what to put there. I'll leave implementing the new constructor as an exercise for you.

It's also not clear if you expect your strings to be null terminated. If you do then you will have to modify the `SubString` code above to add a null terminator. Again I'll leave this as an exercise for you.